# when i try to print a data name using vuejs the variable name is printed as it is instead of the value

Tags: vuejs2

I have the following code using vuejs

## index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>VueJS Tutorials</title>
        <link href="styles.css" rel="stylesheet" />
        <script src="https://unpkg.com/vue"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="vue-app">
            <h1>Hey, {{ name }}</h1>
        </div>
    </body>

    <script src="app.js"></script>
</html>
```

## My app.js

```
new Vue({
    el: '#vue-app',
    data: {
        name: 'Shaun'
    }
});
```

When i run the code using browser, i get the output as

**Hey, {{ name }}**

I am expecting to get

**Hey, Shaun**

What is the problem in my code? Please help

Answer (score 0):

I replaced `<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue"></script>` with
`<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2"></script>` an it worked

Answer (score 0):

`<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue"></script>` import vue3, your code is vue2.
`<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2"></script>` import vue2, so it works.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).